# Can jQuery throw an error from my event handlers?

Tags: jquery, events, yui

I have an error that occurs in a specific event handler that I setup using jQuery and the code just breaks without any errors being displayed. When I used to code similar things in YUI I would setup YAHOO.util.Event.throwErrors = true; in my dev. version and that was telling YUI's event handler to throw errors. I can't find anything similar, is it just me being blind and not seeing it ?

Thanks!

Here's an example...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Events</title>
</head>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.load('jquery', '1.3.2');
</script>
<body>
<p>click me</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("p").click(function() {
            console.log('How to display an error here similar to the native onclick ?');
            qaz;
            console.log('this line is not executed because of the error, but the error is not reported. Is there a way to have jQuery report those errors ?');
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I run this code both event handlers fire & both `console.log` write out to firebug & then it dies on a `qaz` is undefined... is this not what you expect?

Comment: I guess the example was a bit confusing, I changed it now so it's more clear what I'm looking for. If you run it again you will see only one console.log write out and no errors reported. This is how I expect jQuery to work normally, but I want to know if there is a way to make it report the error on qaz; to make for easier debugging ?

Comment: Do you mean Javascript? jQuery does not handle language-level errors. It's a library of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that jQuery won't swallow errors for you, so you should definitely be seeing the error from your undefined `qaz`.

Running your updated page, I still see both the `console.log` and the error on the undefined `qaz` in Firebug. Opening up the normal browser error console, I also see the `qaz is not defined (...temp.html - Line: 15)` message there too. In IE, I of course get `"console" is undefined`, but that just shows that errors are getting through there as well (since there's no console). Assuming you're running that exact same piece of html/js, there's obviously some other variable in play that is causing issues for you.

What version of Firebug are you running? I had various random issues with debugging javascript & the like with version 1.4.x, but 1.5.0 seems much more consistent and stable.

Comment: I was using Firebug 1.5 but after reading what you said I thought I'd check for updates and updated from FF 3.5.7 to 3.6 and sure enough the error does show up now (and also in the real application where I first saw this)

I am 100% sure it wasn't yesterday, so something must have been hung on my machine, and it's not FF 3.5.7 cos I just tried it on a VM now and I get the correct behavior.

I got confused because I used to use YUI and it will swallow up errors in many event handlers unless you set it to not do that.

thanks!